# How to replace local path with global path into href attributes, scraping in python

Tags: python, html, xpath

I trying to scrape some html code from this [site](http://www.dlib.org/dlib/november14/giannakopoulos/11giannakopoulos.html), now when i print all the content, some link (i want only "Table of Contents" and "Printer-friendly Version") have inside the href this string: "../etc". 
When i'm going to print the scraped code i need to replace the local path of the href with the global one, in that way i'll be able to reach the right webpage clicking on my scraped link. In case the requested operation will be not useful, there's a way for write the right path inside the href i need to handle?

```
#!C:/Python27/python
from lxml import etree
import requests

q = "http://www.dlib.org/dlib/november14/giannakopoulos/11giannakopoulos.html"
page = requests.get(q)
tree = etree.HTML(page.text)
element = tree.xpath('./body/form/table[3]/tr/td/table[5]')
content = etree.tostring(element[0])
print "Content-type: text\n\n"
print content.strip()
```

Answer (score 0):

In the resulting HTML, just add an `xml:base` to the root of the document that's the same as the URL of the original page, or any other base URI where you have the same resources.

XPath cannot change the document for you, you will need to that on the document itself. [Etree has a property to set the base URI](http://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree._Element-class.html#base), but I don't know if it will output that when you print the results. The most obvious way to replace this is [to use XSLT](http://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html), which is also supported by lxml.

Setting the base URI will have effect on elements that respect the base URI. Older browsers may not properly respect it, in which case [you can use `<base>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base).